# Reading process memory - frida.ProcessNotRespondingError: process with pid 10308 either refused to load frida-agent, or terminated during injection

Tags: python, windows, memory, frida

I want to read memory of a process (pid = 10308, name ="hello.exe"). I use frida in python 3.10:

```
import frida

def read_process_memory(process_name):
    session = frida.attach(process_name) #error thrown HERE
    memory_map = session.enumerate_ranges("r--")
    memory = b""
    for memory_range in memory_map:
        memory_chunk = session.read_bytes(memory_range.base_address, memory_range.size)
        memory += memory_chunk

    session.detach()
    return memory

memory = read_process_memory("hello.exe")
print(memory)
```

However line

> session = frida.attach(process_name)

throws an error:
frida.ProcessNotRespondingError: process with pid 10308 either refused to load frida-agent, or terminated during injection

The test process is a c++ executable and it is run through File Explorer in Windows 11.

Here is the source code for the simple hello.exe process:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string myString = "SECRET";
    std::cout << "Starting..." << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(60));

    std::cout << "END" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

How can I read memory of a process successfully?

Comment: What C++ compiler/toolchain to you use? Is the created executable a 32 or 64bit executable? To my knowledge Frida Session class has no method `enumerate_ranges` or `read_bytes` so your code will not work. Most likely you are trying to use `Process.enumerateRanges(..)` but that is only possible from within a Frida JavaScript script that you have to load into a session.

Comment: @Robert I used Visual Studio c++ defaults to build hello.exe. It is 64-bit executable. The error is thrown at "session = frida.attach(process_name)". I need to get that going first.

Comment: Try different processes. Windows 10 has a a lot processes (running) you can test with, e.g. `notepad.exe`.